# Sorting JSON by Value in jQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, sorting

I have a JSON file formatted like below:

```
{
    "dislike": 0,
    "like": 15,
    "laugh": 4
}
```

How can I sort the JSON in descending order, so that it looks like this:

```
{
    "like": 15,
    "laugh": 4,
    "dislike": 0
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: objects are meant to be unordered, if you have to sort them maybe convert it to an array, sort it, then convert it back to an object

Comment: It looks like [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-object-property-by-values) answers what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using `object.entries()` to transform the object in an array of entries `[["dislike", 0], ["like", 15], ["laugh", 4]]` to use the **sort** method, so I can order by the position `[1]` of each element in the array that is the entry value.

At the end transform the entries in an object again using `Object.fromEntries()`

```js
json = {
    "dislike": 0,
    "like": 15,
    "laugh": 4
}

const entriesResult = Object.entries(json).sort((v1, v2) => v2[1] - v1[1])

const resultObject = Object.fromEntries(entriesResult)

console.log(resultObject)
```

Comment: This is actually a lot cleaner of an approach than the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069666/sorting-object-property-by-values) people suggested! Thank you!